# How to add 0's in front of a binary number

Tags: java, bit

```
int g = 269;
System.out.println( Integer.toBinaryString(g));//100001101
g<<=10;
System.out.println( Integer.toBinaryString(g));//1000011010000000000
```

I know I can do it like this to add "0"'s after the number, but what if I want to add them before it?

`g>>=1;` won't work, obviously.

Comment: Can't you just pad the String with "0"? If you know how to add 0s to the end, adding them to the beginning is exactly the same process.

Comment: I may want to compare it to other numbers later on, so I need the number padded.

Comment: you are not adding zeros to the number, you are left shifting the bits in the long value.

Comment: Try to use **g & 0xFF**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to print leading zero for an integer, or it's binary representation. How many of them you would like to print? And how would compiler know that on it's own. However, you can always format your string to be padded with zero like this:

```
int g = 269;
String paddedWithZero = String.format("%32s", Integer.toBinaryString(g)).replace(' ', '0');
```

Comment: Ok, I will try using this.